# How do I create an effective mysql database design, where it stores different values for multiple users?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I am trying to make a website, and I need to make a system where it shows random questions, and if the user answers correctly, it exludes the question from the random print.
I need a table where one of the columns is the question number, and one is a boolean, indicating whether or not it has already been answered correctly.
**But I cannot create a table for each user, because it would take too much space. Is there any good ways to create a database in such a way it can manage all users at once?**

I am really lost in what I should do, so I couldn't really try anything.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to do this is to add a `user` field to the table, that is joined by a foreign key conctraint to the `users`' table primary key.

This field needs a (non unique) index and will work as a selector to filter only those questions, that are applicable to a special user.

In your case, using a single key over the `user` field and the `answered` field would create a perfectaccess path for queries with a `WHERE` clause along the lines of `WHERE user=? AND answered=0`

Comment: Im sorry but i think im to begginer to make this way... Im not even understanding the terms youre using. But thanks, really appreciated the time you used to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option to resolve this problems is to create 3 distinct tables;

1º Table -> Users, which will store a `PRIMARY_KEY` as user_id (or whatever name you will give). 
2º Table -> Questions, also will have a `PRIMARY KEY` and a `VARCHAR` with the text 
3º table -> UserQuestion, This table will be a mix of both tables before that will be empty at the begining, but will eventually generate... 
----> this table will relate the user_id with question_id, so you will be able to exclude the questions that will be on this table.

Comment: Ty, i will try to buid this way, but not sure if i can make diferent tables work together... But was a good help anyway i was completly lost.